# Javascript - string to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

How to turn a string into array, using javascript?
In objective-c, I would do the following:

```
NSArray *array=[@"wer;qwe;ert" componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
```

and get `@[@"wer",@"qwe",@"ert"];`

Comment: [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)? Your question doesn't seem to show any research effort...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: Seriously, you're not even going to explain the splitting algorithm.  It's certainly not just a simple delimiter and you're adding characters to the resulting pieces in some cases and ignore part of the original.  Unless you want a bunch of blind guesses, you need to explain what the splitting algorithm should be and then people can offer you the best JS code to split it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a constant delimeter, you can use split.

```
var s = 'something;else';
var a = s.split(';');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var sampleString = 'wer;qwe;ert';
var strArray = s.split(';');
```

The split() method is used to split a string into an array of substrings,
You can see the Sample from W3Schools - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_split

Answer (score 1):

I think String.split() is what you are looking for.

```
var str = "This is a string to be splitted";
var arr = str.split(" ");
```

Split() accepts a delimeter as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

String has a `.split()` method that will allow you to split a string at each occurrence of a supplied delimiter.

```
var data = "wer;qwe;ert",
    values;

values = data.split(";");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6rbJc/